# why my program thorws this error: Cannot perform '=' operation on System.DateTime and System.Int32

Tags: c#, asp.net

why my code throws error
`Cannot perform '=' operation on System.DateTime and System.Int32.`,

this line throws error:

```
DataRow[] dr = ds.Tables[0].Select("HolidayDate=" +  SelectedDate);
```

but when i pass static date like "#2014-10-12#" then it works, i also appended # with selectedDate but program gives no response then.

Complete Code:

```
protected void Calndar_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string SelectedDate = Calndar.SelectedDate.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy") + "-" + "MM-dd");
    DataSet ds = (DataSet)Session["Calendar"];
    DataRow[] dr = ds.Tables[0].Select("HolidayDate=" +  SelectedDate);
    foreach (DataRow drr in dr) 
    {
        Response.Write(SelectedDate);
    }
```

string SelectedDate stores values and also shows in response.write

Updated code also doesn't work

```
protected void Calndar_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime SelectedDate =new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, Calndar.SelectedDate.Month, Calndar.SelectedDate.Day);

    DataSet ds = (DataSet)Session["Calendar"];
    IEnumerable<DataRow> selectedRows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(row => (row.Field<DateTime>("HolidayDate") == SelectedDate));

    foreach (DataRow drr in selectedRows) 
    {
        Response.Write(drr[4]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your .SelectedDate.ToString() looks weird. I'd try to set the desired Date (current year) before actually formatting it to the yyyy-MM-dd string format. If however your HolidayDate column is of datetime data type, the answer of vc74 is the preferred way.

Comment: @JohnNash Did you try to debug this? You should put a little more effort in tracking down problems other than "I clicked on the button and nothing happened".

Comment: i does nothing, not even in debugging

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid such date serialization issues, you can use [Linq to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime selectedDate = 
  new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, Calndar.SelectedDate.Month, Calndar.SelectedDate.Day);
DataSet ds = (DataSet)Session["Calendar"];

IEnumerable<DataRow> selectedRows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().
  Where(row => (row.Field<DateTime>("HolidayDate") == selectedDate));

foreach (DataRow selectedRow in selectedRows) 
...
```